# ejabberd users join different room but same name?

Tags: ejabberd

I set up an ejabberd server and it worked fine. now I changed domain and also generated new ssl cert for new domain name.

However when users login to same room, they end up in their "own" version of the room. They dont see the other users.

How is that possible? How can this be fixed?

I'm using this ejabberd.cfg https://github.com/cryptocat/cryptocat/wiki/Server-Deployment-Instructions

Answer (score 0):

As always, as soon as you are desperate enough to ask the public, you solve it yourself minutes later:
if this error happens, there is sth wrong with your conference server. For me ejabberd config {mod_muc, [{host, "conference.@HOST@"},   the @HOST@  resolved to wrong domain so I hardcoded the correct domain there